# Length Validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

So were given a task that enters 6 digits, I want to put a length validation in my list because i had already done my number validation. for some reason even though i entered six numbers it prints ("6 digits only! Please try again"). anyways this is my code (pardon for the code construction since I just started learning python)

```
while True:

numbers = input("Enter 6 digits: ")
if numbers.isalpha():
    print("Invalid Input!", numbers ," is not a number!")
else:
    NumberList = numbers.split()
    if len(NumberList) == 6:
        print("user list is ", NumberList)
        break
    else:
        print ("6 digits only! Please try again")
```

Comment: What exactly is your input?

Comment: our instructions go like this

1. Ask the user to enter a 6-digit number. Ex. 123456
2. Remove the last digit of the entered number. Ex. Removing the last digit from 123456 returns 12345.
3. Divide the new 5-digit number by 7 and check if its remainder is equivalent to the removed digit in Step 2. Ex. The remainder from dividing 12345 by 7 is 4. The removed digit is 6. Hence, they are not equal.
4. Display the result.

Comment: You cannot run `split()` to split the given string.

Comment: Try replacing `numbers.split()` with `list(numbers)`

Answer (score 1):

The `split` function, called without arguments, splits on whitespaces.

So, your string is not splitted to a list (you obtain only a list with one element, your string).

```
print("123456".split())

['123456']
```

To split the string, in this case, you have to use: `NumberList = list(numbers)`.

```
list("123456")
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

The input would surely give you a string and so you can use the split function, but it expects spaces by default.

So `splitting this string` would result in `['splitting,'this','string']`, but something like `123456`, results in `['123456']` and so the length is always one.

The way to solve this, is to convert the string to a list:

Replace

```
NumberList = numbers.split()
```

with

```
NumberList = list(numbers)
```

This should result in `['1','2','3','4','5','6']` and so should give you a proper length.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    num = input("Enter a Number: ")
    try:
        numbers = [int(i) for i in num]
        if len(numbers) == 6:
            print('valid')
            numbers = numbers[:5]
            print(numbers)
        else:
            print('invalid')
    except ValueError:
        print('only numbers')
```

The number validation is incorrect if you only want numbers. I tried entering numbers first then letters and I got through it.

Comment: I wanted to make it into a list because the second instruction in our activity says that

2. Remove the last digit of the entered number. Ex. Removing the last digit from 123456 returns 12345. any suggestions?

Comment: thaanks, btw question again. in our intsruction it says that 3. Divide the new 5-digit number by 7 and check if its remainder is equivalent to the removed digit in Step 2. Ex. The remainder from dividing 12345 by 7 is 4. The removed digit is 6. Hence, they are not equal. is it applicable in the list?

Comment: Umm. Any math problems are probably out of my range cause of the age. There are a lot a valid answers in your post. You can probably ask them-?

Answer (score 0):

The `string.split()` method with no argument specified, will create a list of substrings, by splitting the original string at any white spaces. If your input is, say `123456`, then `numbers.split()` will produce `["123456"]` since the input string doesn't have any white spaces. In that case, `len(NumberList)` is 1 and that's why it fails your validation.

You could instead just check for `len(numbers) == 6`.

If you want to turn `"123456"` into `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]` (since it seems that's what you want to print), you can use `list(numbers)`

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    numbers = input("Enter 6 digits: ")
    if numbers.isalpha():
        print("Invalid Input!", numbers ," is not a number!")
    else:
        NumberList = len(numbers)
        if NumberList == 6:
            print("user list is", NumberList)
            break
        else:
            print ("6 digits only! Please try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input is something like "123456", first of all, your check `str.isalpha()` will return true only if all the element of the string are letters, meaning that "123asd" would be considered False, and therefore valid for your program, which is a mistake, secondly `str.split()` will only separate the string according to a separator char, the default one is the blank space, if your line is "123456", the result of split, will just be a list of one element with the full string, because there is no space in that line.

```
while True:
    numbers = input("Enter 6 digits: ")
    if sum([n.isalpha() for n in numbers]):
        print("Invalid Input!", numbers ," is not a number!")
    else:
        NumberList = list(numbers)
        if len(NumberList) == 6:
            print("user list is ", NumberList)
            break
        else:
            print("6 digits only! Please try again")
```

Also, there is no need to split the string to a list, if the only operation you need to do is check its lenght, you can just use `len(numbers)`